# React form with lot of children, parent state

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-state-management

I have a form that is basically a matrix of checkboxes (hundreds) and that has one title text input.

Something in those lines :

```
render() {
    <form>
        <input type=text>title</input>
        {checkboxes.map(return <cell />)}
    </form>
}
```

Before, I was saving the global state in the parent, but a single check would take a long time cause the rendering was triggered for every cell.

Now, I have the state (checked true/false) in each cell, so it's faster. I can't really use a function `onChecked` that lift up the state to the parent cause then I fall back to the same slow pattern.

My question is : how should the parent save the global state (so then I can send it to a server for example) ?

I was thinking of just saving all the data in a variable (in the parent, like this.data) not linked to the state since every children is handling its own state.

Thanks

Comment: using `shouldComponentUpdate` handler you can keep the state of all checkboxes in the parent state but re render only those who update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should implement the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method to your `Cell` component. Something like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.checked === this.props.checked) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

This will ensure that re-rendering can never happen if the `checked` prop hasn't changed since last re-render. You should now be able to keep the state in the parent without any lag.

---

Alternatively, but not recommended, you could keep the state to each component and add a `ref` to your `<form>`. This allows you to utilize some of the helper methods out there that are unique to forms and form-elements.

This could look like:

```
<form ref={el => this.formRef = el}>
  ...
```

and

```
onSubmitToServer() {
  const data = jQuery(this.formRef).serializeArray();
  //do something
}
```

Obviously, you would need to install and import jQuery for the above to work, or implement your own solution for serializing the array.

Comment: And what do you think of storing the data internally in the class? (like ``this.data``)

Comment: @HRK44, depends on how you use it. If `this.data` is needed for `render()` and its values change over time its a bad idea and should be in `this.state.data`. If `this.data` is not used in the rendering or is always static, then its fine.